# How to establish a secure AMQP connection in Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, ssl, amqp

I want to establish a TLS-encrypted connection to an AMQP-broker in Windows using Javascript. I don't want to use a client certificate, I only need to accept the brokers certificate, which is signed by a standard certificate authority.

My reference is code from a program running on a Ubuntu system, which looks like this:

```
var options = {

    ca: [fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt")]
};

amqp.connect('amqps://myBroker', options, function(error, connection) {
    
    if (error)
        throw error;

    // Connection established
});
```

The problem is that, from what I've read, there is no equivalent to the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` in Windows. Instead, the CA certificates are stored in a registry entry and you need special tools to access it. I need to do it programmatically though. Also, a lot of the information is really old (including related questions on this site), so I don't know how trustworthy it is .

Has anyone done this before? Or knows a good and up-to-date source?

**Edit:** So there is a command line tool to manage certificates (Certmgr.exe), but that is installed with Visual Studio, so I can't rely on it. The only tool that is installed with Windows itself (Certmgr.msc) is a GUI tool.

Comment: You can absolutely read a CA certificate from a file in Windows. Have you tried it out yourself?

Comment: @LukeBakken Reading in a file is not the problem, but the default trusted authorities are not stored as a file in Windows. They can be exported to a file using a GUI tool, but that would be a manual step anyone had to do when they want to use the application. I'm looking for a completely automated solution.

Comment: This may accomplish what you need - https://github.com/ukoloff/win-ca

Comment: @LukeBakken Looks promising, will check it out. Thanks.